# I want to get latest record in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have two tables Employee and Transaction:

Employee:
[image]

Trans:

[image]

Now I want to get latest record by date from Transaction in which that record have execeution flag as 0 and employee in transaction should be equal to empshortid in employee table.

Output:

1497163 SKANNAN27 0 2012-02-08 19:13:33.840

1498704 AETHODE   0  2012-02-08 18:45:08.380

I will not get other records since for other records if we take max transdate records they have execution flag as '1'. As above output I have many records which should retrieve all.

Please guide me how can i achieve this.

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact SQL Server syntax will be, but you can `ORDER BY TransDate DESC LIMIT 1` to get the latest record.

Comment: @ChrisForrence `LIMIT 1` is MySQL syntax, in SQL Server you use `Top 1` in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: @FrankPl - Ah, thank you. Now I'm glad I didn't make an answer and be wrong ;)

Comment: i think your sample data is not proper because in none of the case employee=emphortid

Answer (score 3):

To get the last record in the `Trans` table with the latest `TransDate` ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3f2da/4/0)):

```
SELECT TOP(1) e.EmployeeID, e.EmpShortID, t.ExecutionFlag, t.TransDate
FROM Employee AS e
INNER JOIN Trans AS t ON t.Employee = e.EmpShortID
WHERE t.ExecutionFlag = 0
ORDER BY t.TransDate DESC
```

**EDIT**, to get the last record in the `Trans` table with the latest `TransDate` for each Employee ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3f2da/2/0)):

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.EmpShortID, t.ExecutionFlag, MAX(t.TransDate)
FROM Employee AS e
INNER JOIN Trans AS t ON t.Employee = e.EmpShortID
WHERE t.ExecutionFlag = 0
GROUP BY e.EmployeeID, e.EmpShortID, t.ExecutionFlag
```

**EDIT**, the below query retrieves the last record in the `Trans` table with the latest `TransDate` for each Employee regardless of the `ExecutionFlag`.  Then it takes those results and pulls only records where the `ExecutionFlag =0` ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/beb1d/14/0)):

```
SELECT m.*
FROM
(
  SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.EmpShortID, MAX(t.TransDate) AS MaxTransDate
  FROM Employee AS e
  INNER JOIN Trans AS t ON t.Employee = e.EmpShortID
  GROUP BY e.EmployeeID, e.EmpShortID
) AS m
INNER JOIN Trans AS tm ON
m.EmpShortID = tm.Employee AND
m.MaxTransDate = tm.TransDate
WHERE tm.ExecutionFlag = 0
```

Comment: if i select top 1 it is giving me only one record but in my table first i have some records with one employee and later some records with other employee..please check my edited post.

Comment: ***@user1912987***, I modifed my answer with what I think you are looking for.  It finds the latest `TransDate` with an `ExecutionFlag` of `0` for each `Employee`.

Comment: The edited answer looks like what the OP is looking for after changing the requirements.

Comment: your sql fiddle getting 3 records as output but according to input in your sql fiddle I should not get RVASUMATHI,SGANDHI6 since their max trans date have exceution flag '1' this is where I am facing the problem

Comment: Sorry I have given wrong output I have checked just now..Please check my update output and tables and help me.

Comment: ***@user1912987***, I updated my answer.  I do believe the second edit is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward query.  Assuming dbo schema:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM dbo.Transaction T
INNER JOIN dbo.Employee E
ON T.Employee = E.EmpshortID
WHERE T.ExecutionFlag = 0
ORDER BY T.TransDate DESC
```

Please see the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d247d/2)

**EDIT**:  Changed for each employee:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Transaction T
INNER JOIN dbo.Employee E
ON T.Employee = E.EmpshortID
WHERE T.ExecutionFlag = 0
ORDER BY T.TransDate DESC
```

Comment: in transaction table I have many records with same employee and different execution flag..I want get only one record with transdate as maximum and check that maximum trans date column whether it has execution flag 0

Comment: There `WHERE` clause will only pull rows that have an Execution Flag of 0.  The `TOP 1` will only pull one record.  It will be the most recent Transaction record since the `ORDER BY` is in `DESC` order.  All of your requirements have been met with this query.

Comment: but I need to get the same for all short ids...please check my edited post it may give you better understanding

Comment: @user1912987 Check updated answer. Returns exactly what you stated in your question.

Comment: I have checked your code in sql fiddle based on that data I should also get RVASUMATHI record since it has execution flag as '0' for highest transdate record..we should not consider trans date on all records it should be considered maximum based on short ids.

Comment: for each short id it should fetch all records then go for max date record and then check execution flag if it is '0' display record otherwise discard the record..same thing should happen for all shortids of employees.

Comment: So then you have changed the requirements on the question and your sample output does not reflect that.  It would be better for future questions if you showed what you expected for all cases, not just one.

Comment: No My requirement is above output for above data because for other short ids if we take max transdate they have execution flag as '1'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1
    *
FROM Employee AS emp
INNER JOIN Transaction AS tran 
    ON tran.Employee = emp.EmpShortID
WHERE tran.ExecutionFlag = 0
ORDER BY TransDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Somethin like that ?

```
 Select top1 from Employee, Transaction 
    where Employee.EmployeeID = Transaction.EmployeeID 
    and ExecutionFlag=0
    order by TransDate desc;
```

Comment: i cannot do order by since i want to retrieve only one record with the short id and that record should have maximum date and need to check that record execution flag

Comment: @Servantwriter, your answer doesn't appear correct.  The OP stated that `EmpShortID` in the `Employee` table should equal `Employee` in the `Transaction` table.

Comment: I think that foreign keys etc have no matter. The whole logic has to be right. You have to do order by and get the first result. You can do order by TransDate, short_id